# Do I need to use the "else" stament for this code?

Tags: php, if-statement

Want to start off by apologizing if this has already been asked; wasn't sure what exactly to search for (did a quick search but didn't find anything).

I have the following basic PHP code (this is just a simple example of what I'm doing anyways):

```
$TestVarOne = 'Test One';

if ( $TestVarOne != '' ) {
    $TempVarOne = 'Hey You ';

    $TestVarOne = $TempVarOne . $TestVarOne;
}
```

What I'm wondering: do I need to bother putting/amending an "else" statement?

What I basically mean is; should I write it this way/add to the code:

```
$TestVarOne = 'Test One';

if ( $TestVarOne != '' ) {
  $TempVarOne = 'Hey You ';

  $TestVarOne = $TempVarOne . $TestVarOne;
} else {
  $TestVarOne = $TestVarOne;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: if and if..else are two different statements, choose it wisely.

Comment: @DannyMyrick IMO, it's opinion-based. If something should fail, how "else" will you know if you don't have a way out of sorts? You don't always have to, but during testing you should. This is just me of course and I'm sure I'm not the only coder on earth who thinks the same way. This is especially when you start coding in OOP or with databases. There are other cases as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply: **no**.

Generally speaking, we should strive for the most readable version of our code (and most efficient).  Adding an else statement that does nothing will complicate your code unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

No. Remember: `else` is not always necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not necessary to use else Please look at export:

```
$TestVarOne = 'Test One';
if ( $TestVarOne != '' ) {
$TempVarOne = 'Hey You ';
echo $TestVarOne = $TempVarOne . $TestVarOne; //Export: Hey You Test One
}
```